# ¿Cómo puedo pasar una varible de una funcion a otra en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

tengo el siguiente codigo en Javascript.

```
function createDownloadLink(blob) {

    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var au = document.createElement('audio');
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var link = document.createElement('a');


    var filename = new Date().toISOString();


    au.controls = true;
    au.src = url;

    link.href = url;
    link.download = filename+".wav"; 
    link.innerHTML = "Convierte tu audio";
    li.appendChild(au);
    li.appendChild(link);
    recordingsList.appendChild(li);
} 
    function descargar(){

}
```

Necesito usar la variable `link` en otra funcion llamada `descargar()` pero no me deja ya que esa varible depende de las demás. ¿Cómo puedo usarla en esa funcion de descargar? Muchas gracias.

Comment: La puedes pasar por referencia, algo así: `descargar(link)` y en la función `descargar` la recibes como parametro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haz el link una variable global.

```js
var link;
function createDownloadLink() {
    link = document.createElement('a');
    }


function descargar(link){
     test.appendChild(link)
    }


createDownloadLink()
descargar(link)
```

```css
a{padding:2em;width:.1em;border:1px solid;display:block;margin:2em auto;}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto

```js
    function createDownloadLink(blob) {

        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var au = document.createElement('audio');
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        var link = document.createElement('a');


        var filename = new Date().toISOString();


        au.controls = true;
        au.src = url;

        link.href = url;
        link.download = filename+".wav"; 
        link.innerHTML = "Convierte tu audio";
        li.appendChild(au);
        li.appendChild(link);
        recordingsList.appendChild(li);

        descargar(link); // se hace el llamado a la otra funcion y se pasa la variable
    } 

    function descargar(link){
      // ya puedes usar la variable link de la otra funcion
      console.log(link);
    }
```

Comment: Me marca que link esta indefinido :(

Comment: tienes que hacer referencia a la variable `refLink` ya que la puse asi en el ejemplo, la estas usando como `link`?

Comment: Sí, hago referencia a `reflink` pero aún así me marca error

Comment: ya modifique el codigo de la respuesta, mira a ver si te sirve